# RDL merge/split rows based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdlc, rdl

I have a dataset like

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9 Column10
1       a       d       1       1       0+1     2       1       2       1
1       b       e       1       1       1+3     8       4       2       1
1       b       e       2       1       1+3     8       4       2       1
1       b       e       3       1       1+3     8       4       2       1
1       b       e       5       1       1+3     8       4       2       1
1       c       f       1       1       0+1     2       1       2       1
```

and I would like my report to show it like

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9 Column10
1       a       d       1       1       0+1     2.00    1       2.00    1
1                       1                       2.00    
1       b       e       2       1       1+3     8.00    4       2.00    1
1                       3                       2.00    
1                       5                       2.00    
1       c       f       1       1       0+1     2.00    1       2.00    1
```

Basically I need to merge rows with the same data together (some columns only). Is it possible to achieve this in rdl? I came across a forum saying this is not possible to achieve in rdl. I have also tried using subreport but couldn't achieve the layout I wanted. Or maybe I need to change the dataset somehow?

Comment: You don't appear to be merging them, just hiding values on subsequent rows, based, I think, on Column4?

Comment: If you want to solve it in SQL then post your SQL as it stands.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, thanks for replying, I need my rdl report to show the rows with same data appear merged for those columns, not exactly hiding them, think more towards Excel way. I don't really want to solve it in SQL but rather in the rdl. But I prepared my dataset in SQL and I worry with its current form it might not be right for me to render the layout I want in rdl. Sorry for causing any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This should work;

```
;with T as
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY     Column1,column2,column3,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10 ORDER BY Column4) rn
,Column1
,column2
,column3
,column4
,column5
,column6
,column7
,column8
,column9
,column10
from <your_table_name>
)
select 
Column1
,case rn     when 1 then column2      else '' end as column2
,case rn     when 1 then column3      else '' end as column3
,column4
,case rn     when 1 then column5      else '' end as column5
,case rn     when 1 then column6      else '' end as column6
,case rn     when 1 then column7      else '' end as column7
,case rn     when 1 then column8      else '' end as column8
,case rn     when 1 then column9      else '' end as column9
,case rn     when 1 then column10     else '' end as column10
from T
```